# what does this loop means: for(j,0,np)

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

```
inline string search_prod(string p) //returns a concatenated string of variables which can produce string p
    {
        int j,k;
        string r="";
        for(j,0,np)
        {
            k=1;
            while(gram[j][k] != "")
            {
                if(gram[j][k] == p)
                {
                    r=concat(r,gram[j][0]);
                }
                k++;
            }
        }   
        return r;
    }
```

I have never seen this loop before.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything, it's not valid syntax. It's probably a typo, using comma `,` instead of semi-colon `;`.

Comment: Search for related macro definition in your code

Comment: Or it's a macro as mentioned by @CinCout (of either `for` or `np`). In which case you should throw away the code as soon as you can, and never look at anything from that author again.

Comment: Does it work? My intuition tells me that it's supposed to run as long as `j`, 0 or `np` is not zero, but since `j` is never modified, `np` isn't defined, I suspect someone is using a macro.

Comment: Doesn't compile [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d3bfec93312e829).

Comment: Will this code even compile?

Comment: Just to throw that into the mix: C != C++. Choose one (probably C++). Anyway, this question can't be answered since you have not provided a [mcve]. The big question is: What is `np`?

Comment: It may be macro defined in your code base. where you are giving three value for start value , termination condition and increment/decrement value.

Comment: It's 2017, and people are still using preprocessor directives in this manner. Makes the programmer in me sad.

Comment: This is a part of this class... (just searched... did not run) ; https://github.com/sudheesh001/LP/blob/master/4.%20CYK%20Algorithm%20C/cyk.cpp

Comment: @AshishJohn Where this is present: `#define for(i,a,b) for(i=a;i<b; i++)`

Comment: That isn't valid C++:  "If a program declares or defines a name in a context where it is reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by this Clause, its behavior is undefined. [...] A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically identical to keywords". (17.6.4.3)

Comment: This is a valid for loop, it is working for me

Comment: @RashidIqbal It is called *undefined behavior* for a reason. It may work as you expect, but that doesn't mean that it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Thanks to @AshishJohn this question is now solvable.

In the provided [link](https://github.com/sudheesh001/LP/commit/3670ba3ca1728aeaf6d38c1cb6b8b926afc63153) you can see a define in the beginning which changes the syntax of for loops:

```
#define for(i,a,b) for(i=a;i<b; i++)
```

So `for(j,0,np)` will be converted by the preprocessor to:

```
for (j=0; j<np; j++)
```

which is a normal for loop. `np` is also declared in the file and is nothing but a global integer variable.

---

However, as @molbdnilo pointed out correctly the standard ([N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)) forbids the declaration of macros that override existing keywords:

> **17.6.4.3.1 Macro names**
>
> 1. A translation unit that includes a standard library header shall not #define or #undef names declared in any standard library header.
> 2. A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically identical to keywords, to the identifiers listed in Table 2, or to the attribute-tokens described in 7.6

Therefore it may or may not behave like I described it.

Comment: Unfortunately for the clever person who came up with that abomination, it is undefined and may or may not expand to whatever.

Comment: Undefined behaviour doesn't require a diagnostic. It may even behave the way you expect from time to time.

Comment: I think it's a fine explanation of what the author meant, just missing a note that it's incorrect to do it.